# Kamon Prometheus takes long to refresh

Tags: akka, prometheus, kamon

I started using Kamon instrumentation recently and facing issues with the rate of the kamon/prometheus http endpoint refresh

**Preface**:

- using `"io.kamon" %% "kamon-bundle" % "2.1.4"` && `"io.kamon" %% "kamon-prometheus" % "2.1.4"`
- exposing metrics as http endpoint so that prometheus scrapes them and evaluates every 1 sec
- created custom Counter, Gauge and Histogram metrics and they are updated 2-3K times per sec inside the Akka actor processing incoming messages
- The reason to use Kamon instead of standard prometheus client is to get thread safety
- There is configuration `kamon.metric.tick-interval 1 second`  & `kamon.prometheus.refresh-interval 1 second` related to the rate of refresh

**Problem**:

Custom metrics that are exposed at the endpoint (localhost:9095) are not refreshed every second. Approximately, they are refreshed every 60 seconds.

It's not prometheus configuration problem, I'm checking the values on the http endpoint exposed by kamon, manually refreshing the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was misconfiguration issue. If you are getting same problem, please make sure that the kamon configuration is on the top level of the `application.conf`, not inside `akka {..}` as I had it